# Nunjucks - How to pass image source to template

Tags: javascript, html, templates, webpack, nunjucks

I'm using Nunjucks as templating language in my project and I have a problem with displaying `img` in `header` component. Problem is, that passed path comes to `img` `src` attribute, but `img` is not displayed. I only get that little icon, which is shown when there is no `img` on provided path. I can't figure out, if it's problem with webback config or it's just me doing something wrong.

So basically, this is how I'm trying to approach this.

```
//Import component
{% from "node_modules/@id-sk/frontend/idsk/components/header-web/macro.njk" import idskHeaderWeb %}

//Use of component
{{ idskHeaderWeb({
  "headerType": "website",
  "brand": {
    "gestor": true,
    "languages": [
      {
        "text": "Slovenčina",
        "selected": "true,",
        "link": "#"
      },
      {
        "text": "Deutsch",
        "link": "#"
      },
      {
        "text": "English",
        "link": "#"
      },
      {
        "text": "Español",
        "link": "#"
      }
    ]
  },
  "main": {
    //Here I'm passing img src path
    "logoSrc": "src/assets/images/vpm-logo.svg",
    "loginButton": {
      "loggedIn":true
    },
    "profileButton": true,
    "secondaryButton": false
  },
  "search": true
}) }}
```

Inside of this component template It looks like this:

```
<a href="/" title="Odkaz na úvodnú stránku">
  {% if params.headerType == 'website' or params.headerType == 'projectWebsite' %}
    {% if main.logoSrc %}
       //Here is passed img src used
       <img src="{{ main.logoSrc }}"
      alt="{{ main.logoAlt if main.logoAlt else 'Ministerstvo investícií, regionálneho rozvoja a informatizácie Slovenskej republiky' }}"
      class="idsk-header-web__main-headline-logo"> 
    {% endif %}
    {% if main.title %}
      <h2 class="govuk-heading-m">{{ main.title }}</h2>
    {% endif %}
  {% endif -%}

  {% if params.headerType == 'electronicService' %}
    <h2 class="govuk-heading-m">{{ main.title if main.title else 'Title text' }}</h2>
  {% endif %}
</a>
```

I have this image stored in my `src/assets/images` folder:

[image]

And I will also provide screenshot from browser, where you can see that `img` `src` path is passed right, but it can't find that image for some other reason:

[image]

Here is also my webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const PostCSSPresetEnv = require('postcss-preset-env');
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require('css-minimizer-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const { WebpackManifestPlugin } = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

module.exports = {
  mode: isDev ? 'development' : 'production',
  stats: {
    colors: true,
    preset: 'minimal'
  },
  performance: { hints: isDev ? false : 'warning' },
  // Eval does not work for css source maps
  // `All values enable source map generation except eval and false value.`
  // https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader
  devtool: isDev ? 'cheap-module-source-map' : 'source-map',
  entry: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/scripts/index.js'),
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/styles/index.scss')
  ],
  output: {
    filename: isDev ? '[name].js' : '[name].[contenthash].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '_site/assets'),
    publicPath: '/assets/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new WebpackManifestPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: isDev ? '[name].css' : '[name].[contenthash].css'
    })
  ],
  ...(!isDev && {
    optimization: {
      minimizer: [
        new TerserPlugin(),
        new CssMinimizerPlugin()
      ]
    }
  }),
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css/i,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: { postcssOptions: { plugins: [PostCSSPresetEnv] } }
          },
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/i,
        type: 'asset',
        generator: {
          filename: `images/${isDev ? '[name][ext]' : '[contenthash][ext]'}`
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: `fonts/${isDev ? '[name][ext]' : '[contenthash][ext]'}`
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      // Helpful alias for importing assets
      assets: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets')
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Obvious `src`-folder is not available for web-users. You should put the image to `public`-folder on webserver, or rewrite rules for this file or use [base64](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html.html) via data:url.

Comment: You need a correct approach of passing src images into your public  folder ocation. right now its not set up in your code.